# What's wrong with this PHP/cURL script attempting to login?

Tags: php, cookies, curl, oauth, instagram

I'm trying to login to Instagram programmatically with PHP and cURL. However, I seem to be missing some detail.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$clientID = (my instagram id);
$redirectURI = (my instagram direct uri);
//$url="https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=".$clientID."&redirect_uri=".$redirectURI."&response_type=token";
$url = "https://instagram.com/accounts/login";

$username = (some username);
$password = (some password);
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31"; // Yes cause that's the way I roll
$cookie="InstagramCookie.txt";

// TODO: find some way to delete the cookie
//unlink($cookie);

$ch  = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/'.$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/'.$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$page = curl_exec($ch);

// try to find the actual login form
if (!preg_match('/<form method="POST" id="login-form" class="adjacent".*?<\/form>/is', $page, $form)) {
    echo "Failed to find log in form!";
    throw Instagram_Manager('Failed to find log in form!');
}

$form = $form[0];

// find the action of the login form
if (!preg_match('/action="([^"]+)"/i', $form, $action)) {
    echo "Failed to login from URL";
    throw Instagram_Manager('Failed to find login form url');
}

$url2 = $action[1]; // this is our new post url
// find all hidden fields which we need to send with our login, this includes security tokens
$count = preg_match_all('/<input type="hidden"\s*name="([^"]*)"\s*value="([^"]*)"/i', $form, $hiddenFields);

$postFields = array();

// turn the hidden fields into an array
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $postFields[$hiddenFields[1][$i]] = $hiddenFields[2][$i];
}

// add our login values
$postFields['username'] = $username;
$postFields['password'] = $password;

$post = '';

//print_r($postFields);

// convert to string, this won't work as an array, form will not accept multipart/form-data, only application/x-www-form-urlencoded
foreach($postFields as $key => $value) {
    $post .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}

$post = substr($post, 0, -1);

//echo $post;
//echo "https://instagram.com".$url2;
//echo $url.$url2;

// set additional curl options using our previous options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$url2);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://instagram.com".$url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$page = curl_exec($ch);

file_put_contents("page.txt", $page);
?>
```

I have some ideas:

1. The `$url` variable is wrong. I want a token for the user, not my app (is there a difference?)
2. Some kind of cookie trouble. I don't really understand how to manage them well. Should I comment out the $cookie variable or delete the cookie some way?

Comment: Are you seeing some error?

Comment: It outputs a .txt file with the HTML that comes back. It's a 404, which is why the URL is probably the culprit. It has to be the $url variable, but I have no idea how to find out what it should be.

Comment: What are you trying to pull out of instagram? Or just want to login?

Comment: I just want to login and get the token. I have an iOS app which should receive the token.